# There was a mismatch between the processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project

Tags: vb.net, oracle12c

I am currently working on a Windows application using visual studio 2010 in 3.5 framework problem, There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=x86", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project
Note: i am using windows 64 bit operating system and database oracle 12c

Comment: That seems to suggest that your project is targeting `Any CPU` while referencing a DLL built against `x86`.  That would mean a 64-bit app on a 64-bit machine but a 32-bit library.  If you're referencing a library that is 32-bit only then your app must be 32-bit only as well.

Comment: but i want to develop this project for 64 bit operating system, and i am using this dll 
https://www.dllme.com/get/26694?captcha

Comment: Why are you getting that library from there in the first place?  If you want to use the Oracle data provider then add it to your project as a NuGet package.  I don't use Oracle so I'm not 100% sure but I think [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess) is the one you need.

Comment: Either you re-compile the referenced libraries to "any CPU", or you don't. If those libraries are set to x86, then you  not be able to run the application as in-process x64. If you can't re-compile or get a set of libraries as x64, or as "any", then I would STRONG suggest you set your project as x86 only.